# having trouble display original and counter offer

Tags: python

I need to be able to display the salary for the next 6 years for an original offer and counter offer. My issue is that my current solution won't display the original offer or the counter I input. It will only display the amounts after the first year.

Here is my solution so far:

```
def main():

    #call get input
    getInput()

    #call calcSalary
    calcSalary()

def getInput():

    #define variables
    startingSalary = 0.0 #counter starting salary
    annualRaise = 0.0 #counter annual raise

    # get input from user for counter offer
    startingSalary = int(input("What is your counter offer for salary?:"))

    annualRaise = int(input("What is your counter offer for annual raise?:"))

    #display table heading
    print("Counter offer:")
    print("Year\tSalary")
    print("---------------")

    #display counter offer for next 6 years
    for year in range(1, 7):
        startingSalary += (annualRaise/100) * startingSalary
        print(year, "\t$", format(startingSalary, ".2f"))

    #return getInput to main function
    return getInput


def calcSalary():

    #define varibales
    startingSalary = 65000 #original salary offer
    anaualRaise = 0.02 #original annual raise offer

    #print table heading
    print("Original offer:")
    print('Year\tSalary')
    print('---------------')

    #display original annual salary
    for year in range(1, 7):
        startingSalary += (.02) * startingSalary
        print(year, "\t$", format(startingSalary, ".2f"))

    #return calcSalary to main function
    return calcSalary

main()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Your code is not at all minimal, requires hand input, and doesn't explicitly show the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

With all that code ... the problem is frustratingly obvious, once the extra lines are stripped away.  You don't get the first-year values because you specifically avoid printing them.  You go directly to the second year's output -- what you label year 1.  Just add a line in each routine to print the original salary before you go into your loop to calculate raises.

```
        print(0, "\t$", format(startingSalary, ".2f"))
```

before the loop in each routine.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to rearrange your print statements:

```
for year in range(7):
    print(year, "\t$", format(startingSalary, ".2f"))
    startingSalary += (annualRaise/100) * startingSalary

for year in range(7):
    print(year, "\t$", format(startingSalary, ".2f"))
    startingSalary += annualRaise * startingSalary
```